# A client error (InvalidClientTokenId) occurred when calling the ListAccountAliases operation: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

everyone

I'm trying to use to AWS S3 and aws-cli, but I simply get the following error for all my command line inputs.

```
A client error (InvalidClientTokenId) occurred when calling the ListAccountAliases operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

1. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.1 and installed `aws-cli` via `sudo pip install awscli`
2. I created a user on IAM console and set the relevant policies to the user.
3. I set up configuration for `aws-cli` by running `aws configure`
4. I created a bucket on S3 console and set a policy to allow the above user to access this bucket.

However, all commands (that I know) on the command line (terminal) gave me the above error, and I cannot find any information about this.

I tried,

`aws s3 ls`

`aws s3 ls s3://<my bucket name>`

`aws iam list-account-aliases`

Is there anyone who can help me to solve this issue?

Best regards,

Jaehyun

Comment: Are you sure you copied your credentials correctly? Does your account require MFA? That could also be it.

Comment: @JordonPhillips Hi, thank you for your comments. It was the credential problem. After seeing your comment, I made a new user, and it works. I think somehow I didn't copy my credentials properly. Thank you so much!